# R convert matrix to list

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a large matrix

```
> str(distMatrix)
 num [1:551, 1:551] 0 6 5 Inf 5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:551] "+" "ABRAHAM" "ACTS" "ADVANCE" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:551] "+" "ABRAHAM" "ACTS" "ADVANCE" ...
```

which contains numeric values. I need to gather all numeric values into ONE long list (for acquiring distribution). Currently what I have:

```
for(i in 1:dim(distMatrix)[[1]]){
    for (j in 1:1:dim(distMatrix)[[1]]){
      distances[length(distances)+1] <- distMatrix[i,j]
    }  
  }
```

However, that takes forever. Can anyone suggest a faster way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To turn a matrix into a list, the length of which is the same as the number of elements in the matrix, you can simply do

```
as.list(distMatrix)
```

This goes down the columns, but you can use the transpose

```
as.list(t(distMatrix))
```

to make it go across the rows.  Since your matrix is 551x551 it should be sufficiently efficient.